# How can online/offline versions of an HTML5 app access the same LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, html5-appcache, electron

A benefit often mentioned (e.g., [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage), [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)) about HTML5 LocalStorage is support for offline apps.  However, the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) makes me think that an app at foo.com won't see the same LocalStorage as it would if the user downloaded the HTML files of the app and pointed their browser to those files on their local drive.  (The same-origin policy is also [restrictive with apps loaded from file:// URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096444/html5-localstorage-for-offline-websites)).

My questions:

1. My web app must read/write LocalStorage *and* be usable offline, still reading/writing the same LocalStorage.  Is the correct way to support that an [app manifest](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)?  I.e., if I use an app manifest, when the user tries to visit foo.com when offline, I think he/she will get the cached version, and yet the domain will still count as if the user were online.  Is that right?
2. I assume that this does *not* work the same if I create a local app using a wrapper like [Atom shell](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell).  I.e., the same-origin policy will mean that the user will *not* be able to access the same LocalStorage inside the wrapped version of my app as they would from their browser.  Is that right?

Comment: Right on both accounts.

Comment: Hi, @dave. Thanks for the quick response. If you want to put that as an answer, as opposed to a comment, with links to sources for the official record, I'm glad to accept it.